# Event Handles Button.Click

Tags: vb.net

Hello here is what i want to do:

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click
        MyUpdate.CheckUpdate("version.txt")
        If MyUpdate.CurrentVersion < MyUpdate.UpdateVersion Then
            'IF USER PRESS THE BUTTON TO RAISE EVENT ONE MORE TIME

        Else
           'DO NOTHING
        End If
    End Sub
```

I don't know how to raise an event within an event. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure your not calling UpdateButton_Click with RaiseEvent (method talked about below) ... you could run into an infinite loop if that IF statement is almost always true.

Comment: Well It seems i'll just have to add another button...

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively enough, you use the [`RaiseEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed.aspx) keyword.

More explanation about raising and consuming events in VB.NET can be found [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973905.aspx).

But in this case it's probably better to refactor your code and extract the logic out of event handler method into another function.

Comment: I don't get it, with MSDN references. Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: @Dev: There are examples and then more examples in the linked article. What seems to be the problem?